# Only last row inserts after foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, json

this is my `info.php` file. In this file I'm getting `steam_id` from `scammers` table. Problem is when I display results in front page all players parameters are the same because the same last row from table `scammers` always inserts into `$steamids`. Why it's not inserting one by one ? That causes my problem and I don't know how to fix this.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=csgoscam', 'root', '');

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM scammers");
$sth->execute();
$row = $sth->fetchAll();
$data = [];

foreach($row as $r){

    $steamids = $r['steam_id'];

    $APIKEY = '***';
    $steamAPI = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?steamids=$steamids&key=$APIKEY&format=json";
    $json_object= file_get_contents($steamAPI);
    $data[] = json_decode($json_object);

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

My app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
        $.each(json, function(i, player){
            //console.log(player.response.players[0].avatarfull);
       $(".userinfo").html('<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="'+player.response.players[0].avatarfull+'">');
       $(".steamProfile").html('<a href="'+player.response.players[0].profileurl+'">STEAM nuoroda</a>');
       $(".personaname").html(player.response.players[0].personaname);
       });
    });
});
```

`info.php`:

[info.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mldaS.png)

**UPDATE** this is how it looks like with append

[append image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnzZZ.png)

`Html`

```
<div class="profiles col-md-4">

<div class="userinfo"></div>
<p>Slapyvardis: <strong><span class="personaname"></span></strong></p>
<p>Vardas: <strong>{{$s->fname}} {{$s->lname}}</strong></p>
@if($s->facebook == "")
<p>Facebook: <strong>Nėra</strong></p>
@else
<p>Facebook: <strong>{{$s->facebook}}</strong></p>
@endif
<p>Skype ID: <strong>{{$s->skype_id}}</strong></p>
<p>Steam ID: <strong><span id="steamID">{{$s->steam_id}}</span></strong></p>-->
<p>Steam URL: <strong><span class="steamProfile"></span></strong></p>

<p style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"><button id="reason" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reasonText{{$s->id}}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></i> Rodyti priežastį</button>

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#proofText{{$s->id}}" id="proof" class="btn btn-success">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> <strong>Įrodymai</strong></button>

<form id="voteUp" action="/minus-rep/{{$s->id}}" method="get">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> <strong>Nerekomenduoti</strong></button>
</form>

</p>
<p>Nerekomenduoja: <strong><span id="votes" class="label label-success">{{$s->points}}</span></strong>

@if($s->points < 2 && $s->points > 0) 
    narys
@endif
@if($s->points > 1 && $s->points < 10)
    nariai
@endif
@if($s->points > 10)
    narių
@endif  
</p>

</div>
```

Comment: @SearchAndResQ I've updated my answer

Comment: Could you do `echo $r['steam_id'];` in your foreach and see what the output is?

Comment: Why using $r['steam_id'] in every iteration if it actually gets all rows? Shouldn't you use $row inside the foreach loop? And if you really want to get all ids, get it out of the foreach.

Comment: @isnisn I get all the steamids

Comment: @omegasbk Than how to foreach the rest code without `$row` ?

Comment: My bad, I switched $r and $row in my mind

Comment: I added the image file

Comment: in your loop `$(".userinfo").html('content');` overwrites the innerHTML each iteration. You need something like `$(".userinfo").append('content');`

Comment: @RolandStarke Okay, now it shows both avatars next to each other in both columns in front page.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your js with this (credit to @roland-starke)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.getJSON("/info.php", function(json){
        $.each(json, function(i, player){
            //console.log(player.response.players[0].avatarfull);
       $(".userinfo").append('<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" src="'+player.response.players[0].avatarfull+'">');
       $(".steamProfile").append('<a href="'+player.response.players[0].profileurl+'">STEAM nuoroda</a>');
       $(".personaname").append(player.response.players[0].personaname);
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question how it looks with append

Comment: I don't know what your underlying html looks like. It seems as though you have two `.steamProfile` divs or spans on that page, and the result is a duplication of everything. It looks to me like there are two images (one green and one not) and two links (both with text "STEAM nuoroda") in each of two divs.

Comment: Hey I aded my html code. But I'm thinking that I should write him all in JS file where the json is and just append that `profiles` div. But then how to get values from `{{$s->}}` ?

Comment: Your code is basically working. The entire `<div class="profiles col-md-4">` is duplicated in the screenshot you sent, but each one is showing two images, two user names, and two links, set by the javascript. So your javascript is getting the correct information. You just need to decide how to display it.

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to write all `<div class="profiles col-md-4">` code in javascript code. But it's kinda hard to get variables from there